# Routing to action getting only one ID from the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Im trying to make a custom router for my mvc-learning project. 
I want to keep the standrard route that directs to  {controller}/{action}/{id} in case of a URL like 
domain.com/user/details/72

but if i get a url like this one
domain.com/2 
i want to route to a specifik controller action that takes the number as an id. So i dont want the URL to specify controller and action, cause i want the url to be real short and the controller and action should always be the same.

Ive kind of made it work but i get very strange unpredictable results so i wanted to ask if im doing something very weird. Here are my routes:

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "DisplayKombak",
         url: "{kombakId}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Kombak", action = "DisplayKombak", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the strange unpredictable results you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DisplayKombak",
            url: "{kombakId}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Kombak", action = "DisplayKombak"}
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```

And KombakController.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class KombakController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult DisplayKombak(string kombakId)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! What is the difference between my route config and yours? I can only see that yours dont have the URLParameter.Optional on the first routemapping. Is that it?

Comment: That changed everything! Thanks.

Comment: Please note 2 most important things about routes.
1. Pattern.
2. Order.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to force this behavior by adding route constraints.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "DisplayKombak",
  url: "{kombakId}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Kombak", action = "DisplayKombak", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new {kombakId = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new {controller = @"\D+" }
);
```

The constraint on the first route will prevent the route from matching unless the first route segment is an integer, the constraint on the second route will prevent the route from matching if the first route segment is not a string of letters.

Comment: Even if it didnt solve my problem it was a great help and i learned something important. Thanks!